# Converting date that is a Stringtype into Int in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have a dataset looking like this:
item_nbr | date
123      | 2016-09-23
123      | 2016-10-23
112      | 2016-08-15
112      | 2016-09-15

I use groupByKey to make it look like this:
'123',['2016-09-23','2016-10-23']
'112',['2016-08-15','2016-09-15']
Now I want to calculate the difference between these two dates. I have a function that looks like this:

```
def ipi_generate(x):
    member_ipi_list = []
    master_ans = []
    for j in range(1,len(x[1])):
        ans = x[1][j]-x[1][j-1] 
        master_ans.append(ans)
    member_ipi_list.append(x[0])
    member_ipi_list.append(master_ans)
    return [member_ipi_list]
```

Which treats the date as if it's string. How do I convert my string date into a int date in pyspark?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the datetime library? As in `datetime.strptime(x[1][j], '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are not transforming these to datetime objects *before* grouping by key? I'm also not aware of your larger goal, so this may or may not be appropriate, but Window functions  or aggregating functions might be easier here. Look into them.

Comment: Used the datetime library in the function now. Worked fine, thanks. :) I tried transforming the string to datetime objects but that is not how the final output is required so did not do do it before grouping by key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use window functions instead of using UDF:

First let's create our dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([["123", "2016-09-23"], ["123", "2016-10-23"], ["123", "2016-11-23"], ["123", "2017-01-01"], ["112", "2016-08-15"], ["112", "2016-09-15"]]), 
    ["item_nbr", "date"]
)
```

Now let's use a lag function to bring on the same row our current's row date and the date of the previous row:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("item_nbr").orderBy("date")
df.withColumn(
    "date_diff", 
    psf.datediff("date", psf.lag("date").over(w))
).show()

    +--------+----------+---------+
    |item_nbr|      date|date_diff|
    +--------+----------+---------+
    |     112|2016-08-15|     null|
    |     112|2016-09-15|       31|
    |     123|2016-09-23|     null|
    |     123|2016-10-23|       30|
    |     123|2016-11-23|       31|
    |     123|2017-01-01|       39|
    +--------+----------+---------+
```